# Google Drive API v3- create a folder inside a folder in Java

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to develop a method in Java that enables creating a folder inside of a specific folder in Google Drive, but what I found in Google documentation (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder) is creating only a folder or moving a file to a folder. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In the API under the `Inserting a File in a Folder` it has this line `The parents property can be used when creating a folder as well to create a subfolder.`

Since you have the Folder ID of the parent folder, just use that like you were creating a plain folder but add `fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderId));` to it along with `File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata)
    .setFields("id, parents")
    .execute();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take what the API gave you for creating a folder and inserting a file in a folder and combine them.

From the API site: 'The `parents` property can be used when creating a folder as well to create a subfolder.'

```
String folderId = "folderID";
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("Invoices");
fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderId));
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata)
.setFields("id, parent")
.execute();
System.out.println("Folder ID: " + file.getId());
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, it worked! Only a simple mistake while defining the field parent in setFields() call. The field name is "parents" (plural), not parent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a drive service first. Then you can call createSubFolder method.

```
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
```

Resource Link: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java

Here, 
It is required to give id of parent folder.
And have to give the sub folder name.

```
public String createSubFolder(String parentFolderId, String subFolderName) {
    System.out.println("Sub Folder Name: "+subFolderName);
    File file = null;
    try {
        File fileMetadata = new File();
        fileMetadata.setName(subFolderName);
        fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");
        if (parentFolderId != null) {
            List<String> parents = Arrays.asList(parentFolderId);
            fileMetadata.setParents(parents);
        }
        file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata).setFields("id, name").execute();
        System.out.println("Folder ID: " + file.getId());
        return file.getId();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: what is the root folder id?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to create a folder in a **shared drive** you have to specify following:

- drive id  (to file metadata)
- supports all drives (to the files().create().setFields in builder chain)

  ```
  private String createFolder(String folderName, String parent) throws IOException {

       System.out.println("Creating folder " + folderName + " in " + parent);

       File fileMetadata = new File();
       fileMetadata.setParents(Arrays.asList(parent));
       fileMetadata.setName(folderName);
       fileMetadata.setDriveId(DRIVE_ID);
       fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

       File file = drive.files().create(fileMetadata)
                          .setSupportsAllDrives(true)
                          .setFields("id")
                          .execute();

       System.out.println("created folder ID: " + file.getId());

       return file.getId();
  }
  ```